# tag a Facebook friend in status through the application

Tags: flash, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-as3-api

How to let the user tag a Facebook friend for status wall post through the application
(using AS3 SDK)

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, you can't tag users like this using the Graph API. The functionality you're looking for is a feature limited to the Facebook website only.